# Automatically alter letterspacing (intra-word spacing) to avoid loose lines with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, typography, microtype

In the book `The Complete Manual of Typography` by James Felici, it is recommended to sometimes alter the spaces between letters in order not to stretch the inter-word spaces too dramatically.

[image]

I have tried using `Tracking` from `microtype` package, but I can only set it to the constant value. There is also `LetterSpace` option in `fontspec`, but it seems to do pretty the same.

Can this be done in `LuaLaTeX`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[
        expansion   =   false,
        tracking    =   alltext,
    ]{microtype}

\SetTracking{
    family  =   *}{10} 

\begin{document}

    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: A related link from the typography perspective: it's worth knowing that typographers' opinions on such letter spacing (and font expansion: basically all the features provided by microtype!) [differ](http://www.typografi.org/justering/oppfatninger/syn_english.html).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR AFAIK there is a big controversy around the `expansion`, but i find alterning the spaces OK. Is this very feature provided by `microtype`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although [typographers differ in their opinion](http://www.typografi.org/justering/oppfatninger/syn_english.html) on letter spacing, when setting justified text in narrow columns we have to settle for some compromise somewhere (which includes considering ragged-right text), and letter spacing seems acceptable. So I am shocked that the `microtype` package does not seem to provide this feature; after all it is extensively discussed in Hàn Thế Thành's thesis [*Micro-typographic extensions to the TeX typesetting system*](http://www.pragma-ade.com/pdftex/thesis.pdf). I am still not sure whether I simply missed something in the `microtype` documentation, though I looked through it several times for this feature.

Anyway, this is easy to do with LuaTeX. There are multiple approaches: for example, after line-breaking (in `post_linebreak_filter`) we could add the appropriate amount of stretch between nodes (this is the approach discussed in Hàn Thế Thành's thesis, section 6.8). Or else, before line-breaking (in `pre_linebreak_filter`) we could add stretchable glue nodes. The second approach is implemented in the `chickenize` package, as `\letterspaceadjust`. It's just a handful of lines of code, so we can copy it and make changes if we desire (in the code sample below I change only `letterspace_glue.stretch` from 0.5 pt to 10pt).

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}

\usepackage{chickenize}

\begin{document}
\hsize=15em
\frenchspacing
\def\\{\penalty-10000}
\def\sample{
The results of the first round of\\
the elections shook the public\\
rigid, as it seemed impossible\\
that a candidate from the far\\
right wing---who indeed had\\
been a Nazi Party member dur-\\
ing his youth---ousted the cen-\\
ter-left candidate. The outcry\\
from the general public was\\
considerable but also considera-\\
bly too late. The run-up to the\\
election had been somnolent---and\\
people learned too late that the\\
unimaginable only seems that\\
way when people fail to use\\
their imagination.}

\noindent The default:

\sample

\lipsum[1]


\newpage
\noindent Best result without letter spacing:
\tolerance=9999 \hfuzz=0.1pt \emergencystretch=\hsize

\sample

\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\noindent With letter spacing:
\letterspaceadjust

\sample

\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\noindent Exaggerated letter spacing:
\unletterspaceadjust
\begin{luacode}
local nodeid   = node.id
local nodenew  = node.new
local nodecopy = node.copy
local nodetraverseid = node.traverse_id
local nodeinsertbefore = node.insert_before

local letterspace_glue   = nodenew(nodeid"glue")
local letterspace_pen    = nodenew(nodeid"penalty")
letterspace_glue.width   = tex.sp"0pt"
letterspace_glue.stretch = tex.sp"10pt"
letterspace_pen.penalty  = 10000
letterspaceadjust = function(head)
  for glyph in nodetraverseid(nodeid"glyph", head) do
    if glyph.prev and (glyph.prev.id == nodeid"glyph" or glyph.prev.id == nodeid"disc" or glyph.prev.id == nodeid"kern") then
      local g = nodecopy(letterspace_glue)
      nodeinsertbefore(head, glyph, g)
      nodeinsertbefore(head, g, nodecopy(letterspace_pen))
    end
  end
  return head
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",letterspaceadjust,"letterspaceadjust")
\end{luacode}

\sample

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

---

Just for clarity, here is the relevant code again, without loading it from a package. Put the following in a file called `letterspacing.lua`:

```lua
local interletter_glue   = node.new('glue')
interletter_glue.width   = tex.sp(0)
interletter_glue.stretch = tex.sp('0.5 pt') -- This number controls how much the space between letters can stretch.
local interletter_pen    = node.new('penalty')
interletter_pen.penalty  = 10000

add_interletter_glue = function(head)
   -- Adds equivalent of "\penalty10000\hskip 0pt plus 0.5pt" (the above penalty and glue)
   -- before every letter (glyph) that follows a glyph, discretionary (hyphen), or kern node.
   for glyph in node.traverse_id(node.id('glyph'), head) do
      if glyph.prev and (glyph.prev.id == node.id('glyph') or
                         glyph.prev.id == node.id('disc') or
                         glyph.prev.id == node.id('kern')) then
         local g = node.copy(interletter_glue)
         node.insert_before(head, glyph, g)
         node.insert_before(head, g, node.copy(interletter_pen))
      end
   end
   return head
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", add_interletter_glue, "Allow variable interletter spacing.")
```

Now you can typeset the following file with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}                                            % For random text
\begin{document}
\hsize=10em \frenchspacing              % Just to make the effects easier to see
\tolerance=9999 \emergencystretch=\maxdimen  % Work harder, avoid overfull boxes

\lipsum                                 % This is typeset without letter-spacing

\directlua{dofile('letterspacing.lua')}                 % Turn on letter-spacing

\lipsum                                    % This is typeset with letter-spacing
\end{document}
```

You can control the amount of allowed stretching by changing the value of `interletter_glue.stretch` (third line of `letterspacing.lua`) (though note that by setting `\emergencystretch` we're explicitly telling TeX to exceed that limit if necessary… however, you usually won't need `\emergencystretch` with letter-spacing, in many cases where you would have needed it otherwise).

Comment: I also haven't seen this feature in `microtype`, which is strange. Where exactly is the tracking controlled in your code?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Search for `letterspace_glue.stretch` in the code… I added another version to try to make this clearer (in which search for `interletter_glue.stretch`).

Comment: `microtype` doesn't provide this feature because `pdftex` doesn't: paragraph composition with variable letterspacing was possible in early versions, but this was later dropped, leaving font expansion as the only option to improve justification.

Comment: @Robert Thank you so much! That explains it… makes sense now.

Comment: Just to note that the output would be improved if the glue were also allowed to shrink.